# What is the `.git/objects/info` directory

Tags: git

Inside `.git/objects` directory there's  the `info` subdirectory. What is it used for? I know what `.git/objects` directory used for and what is `.git/objects/pack` directory. But I can't find information on the `.git/objects/info` directory. It can be somewhere on the surface but `info` is too overly generic name to search in google - too many irrelevant results.

Comment: Why -1, this is a legit question. (Counter +1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Repository layout documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout#gitrepository-layout-objectsinfo):

> **objects/info**
> Additional information about the object store is recorded in this directory.
>
> **objects/info/packs**
> This file is to help dumb transports discover what packs are available in this object store. Whenever a pack is added or removed, git update-server-info should be run to keep this file up-to-date if the repository is published for dumb transports. git repack does this by default.
>
> **objects/info/alternates**
> This file records paths to alternate object stores that this object store borrows objects from, one pathname per line. Note that not only native Git tools use it locally, but the HTTP fetcher also tries to use it remotely; this will usually work if you have relative paths (relative to the object database, not to the repository!) in your alternates file, but it will not work if you use absolute paths unless the absolute path in filesystem and web URL is the same. See also objects/info/http-alternates.
>
> **objects/info/http-alternates**
> This file records URLs to alternate object stores that this object store borrows objects from, to be used when the repository is fetched over HTTP.

So it's purely internal to git.

For example:

```
$ cat .git/objects/info/packs
P pack-fac58f9273f12d454896cdc6070b9607e271e530.pack

$ ls -1 .git/objects/pack/
pack-597bfea331852c930d2cd014e0328c458417ea05.pack
pack-d5589be9a1ca818d38efb0e9f185cc816f4749ad.pack
pack-fac58f9273f12d454896cdc6070b9607e271e530.idx
pack-fac58f9273f12d454896cdc6070b9607e271e530.pack
```

It's used in [http.c#http_get_info_packs](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3622a4ee94e4916cd05e6d96e41eeb36b941182/http.c#L1945) used by [https-push.c#fetch_indices](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e629a7d28a405e48fae6b064a781a10e885159fc/http-push.c#L705).

Comment: Updated my answer, but it's purely git internals. You can find for `info/packs` by searching in the code: https://github.com/git/git/search?p=1&q=%22info%2Fpacks%22&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 1):

The notion of info/alternates goes back to With Git 1.4 (Q2 2006),

See [commit 0438402](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0438402271cccc1711c603b0a7ba3134f1ce30f1), [commit dd05ea1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd05ea1799656024a45017238bbd4857b5256370), [commit c2f493a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2f493a4ae159ef99b20be490ae603cd13bab4eb), [commit 178613c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/178613c737f82489a1e2c387236731541fe19081), [commit cf9dc65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf9dc65368113caa28f2829e2ada5477fbb031ec) (07 May 2006) by [Martin Waitz (`tali`)](https://github.com/tali).
See [commit fd60aca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd60acaced6de16ebfb66959067e2b29f99a133e), [commit 6fe31e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fe31e2e4cdb7ed5333107174e23fbf2e226e370) (07 May 2006) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit d92f1dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d92f1dc63f0582e7cf8dac54d50a2748119a1ce3) (07 May 2006) by [Peter Hagervall (`phagervall`)](https://github.com/phagervall).
See [commit 5d8ee9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d8ee9ceb8912c83336191d32b8898943b8944b8) (07 May 2006) by [Pavel Roskin (`proski`)](https://github.com/proski).
See [commit 245f102](https://github.com/git/git/commit/245f1029d674b95d63b5faea2269f98d28b3adb2) (07 May 2006) by [Matthias Lederhofer (`matled`)](https://github.com/matled).
See [commit be65e7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be65e7d9fbd3ae6fc097cedade2afe39805fcf4e) (07 May 2006) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7f49806](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f498065e9bf85f6f3e954ec57dedf56fec29e01), 07 May 2006)</sup>

> ### [`c2f493a4ae`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2f493a4ae159ef99b20be490ae603cd13bab4eb):Transitively read alternatives
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Martin Waitz</sup>

> When adding an alternate object store then add entries from its info/alternates files, too.
> Relative entries are only allowed in the current repository.
> Loops and duplicate alternates through multiple repositories are ignored.
> Just to be sure that nothing breaks it is not allow to build deep nesting levels using info/alternates.

But recently (2021), it evolved with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), which adds optimization for repositories with many **alternate object store**.

See [commit 92d8ed8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92d8ed8ac101d62183d51f280b90efb1de1bda5c), [commit 90e07f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90e07f0a342df836a33b92e179eb105243dba88d), [commit 33f379e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33f379eee63a0529f85079857598ac6325d3aec5), [commit 407532f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/407532f82d3fdfd18d4ec276ddeb359e7c724aa6), [commit cf2dc1c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf2dc1c238c6fd5f93c315a3045ccf95459701cd) (07 Jul 2021) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e5cc59c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5cc59c77c875aeda93a3cdfe70c8254164324ab), 28 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`oidtree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92d8ed8ac101d62183d51f280b90efb1de1bda5c): a `crit-bit` tree for `odb_loose_cache`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Wong</sup>

> This saves 8K per `struct` object_directory`', meaning it saves around 800MB in my case involving 100K alternates (half or more of those alternates are unlikely to hold loose objects).
>
> This is implemented in two parts: a generic, allocation-free `cbtree` and the `oidtree` wrapper on top of it.
> The latter provides allocation using `alloc_state` as a memory pool to improve locality and reduce free(3) overhead.
>
> Unlike `oid-array`, the **[`crit-bit` tree](https://cr.yp.to/critbit.html)** does not require sorting.
> Performance is bound by the key length, for `oidtree` that is fixed at `sizeof(struct object_id)`.
> There's no need to have 256 `oidtrees` to mitigate the O(n log n) overhead like we did with `oid-array`.
>
> Being a prefix trie, it is natively suited for expanding short object IDs via prefix-limited iteration in `find_short_object_filename`.
>
> On my busy workstation, p4205 performance seems to be roughly unchanged (+/-8%).
> Startup with 100K total alternates with no loose objects seems around 10-20% faster on a hot cache.
> (800MB in memory savings means more memory for the kernel FS cache).
>
> The generic `cbtree` implementation does impose some extra overhead for `oidtree` in that it uses `memcmp(3)` on "`struct object_id`" so it wastes cycles comparing 12 extra bytes on SHA-1 repositories.
> I've not yet explored reducing this overhead, but I expect there are many places in our code base where we'd want to investigate this.

And, still with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), a build fix:

See [commit 581a3bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/581a3bb155c157094ca486e3a10c4a9b70c8f650) (06 Aug 2021) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
See [commit dd3c8a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd3c8a72a2eaecf0c752a37e1f4ba4de59818e93), [commit 1482594](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14825944d7c57b6acd7e1a05a4c6046965efc6a5) (08 Aug 2021) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7cfaa86](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cfaa86fe6f61698752d13c59ac97a102d1fbaae), 11 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`object-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/581a3bb155c157094ca486e3a10c4a9b70c8f650): use unsigned arithmetic with bit mask
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> [33f379e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33f379eee63a0529f85079857598ac6325d3aec5) ("make `object_directory.loose_objects_subdir_seen` a bitmap", 2021-07-07, Git v2.33.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5cc59c77c875aeda93a3cdfe70c8254164324ab) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/940fe202adcbf9fa1825c648d97cbe1b90d26aec)) replaced a wasteful 256-byte array with a 32-byte array and bit operations.
> The mask calculation shifts a literal 1 of type int left by anything between 0 and 31.
> `UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer` doesn't like that and reports:
>
> [`object-file.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/581a3bb155c157094ca486e3a10c4a9b70c8f650/object-file.c):2477:18: runtime error: left shift of 1 by 31 places cannot be represented in type 'int'
>
> Make sure to use an unsigned 1 instead to avoid the issue.

```
 size_t mask = 1 << (subdir_nr % word_bits);
 size_t mask = 1u << (subdir_nr % word_bits); <==
```