# What are the references within Git's pack/ and info/ folders?

Tags: git, .git-folder

I have read the relevant git documentation:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References

I have not found any information about the `.git/objects/refs/heads/info` directory; though I understand that `.git/objects/refs/heads/pack` is for pack-files.

However, it is permitted to create branches such as:

```
$ git branch info/my_branch
$ git branch pack/my_branch
```

which will then be located at `.git/objects/refs/heads/info/my_branch` and `.git/objects/refs/heads/info/my_branch`.

I am writing a Python script in order to parse my Git objects in a certain way, with one step being to look for all the branch references. I realize now I need to also look into `info` and `pack` and sort out conflicts.

What is the `info` directory typically used for otherwise?

Comment: Do you really need to look inside the `.git` directory to discover branches, or could you just use `git for-each-ref` instead? That way you don't need to worry about the details of how `git` stores things.

Comment: I am manually doing it using Python only. I do not want to run any subcommands. I'm more asking about the purpose of `info/`, not so much as to how I could make my implementation different ( it is an exercise for me ).

Comment: I don’t have `.git/objects/refs/heads/info`. I also don’t have `.git/objects/refs/heads/pack`.

Comment: [What is the `.git/objects/info` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813786/what-is-the-git-objects-info-directory#45814033)

Answer (score -1):

The info() method prints information about the DataFrame. The information contains the number of columns, column labels, column data types, memory usage, range index, and the number of cells in each column (non-null values). Note: the info() method actually prints the info.

Comment: Are you referring to Panda’s `DataFrame.info()`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was talking about Git's `.git/objects/refs/heads/info` directory. It wasn't talking about DataFrame's or any kind of `info()` method.

Comment: it litterally said he wanted the porpose of the info() method not so much as to how he could make his implementation different